# How do I get the url from overlay after loading with jQuery tools?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, overlay

I'm using [jquery tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/) overlay plugin. In the overlay I load a specific url. After the url is loaded in the overlay, how do I get this url from jquery?

Update:

My code looks like the jquery overlay [open external link example](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/external.html)

The reason I want to know the url is because I have some parameters set in there I am trying to access.

Comment: Post your code - it depends how you do it and where you need the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the basic code:

```
// if the function argument is given to overlay,
// it is assumed to be the onBeforeLoad event listener
$("a[rel]").overlay({
    mask: 'darkred',
    effect: 'apple',
    onBeforeLoad: function() {

        // grab wrapper element inside content
        var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");

        // load the page specified in the trigger
        wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));

        // save the currently-loaded URL as a data field on the wrapper
        wrap.data('currenturl',this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
    }
});
```

Then all you need to get the URL is this:

```
$(".contentWrap").data('currenturl');
```